# How to avoid duplicate id references inside Jinja2 if-else statements

Tags: html, flask, pycharm, jinja2

In my app.py, I have a controller rendering some page.

In this page, there is a form with a field that is empty by default. The user can input a value, foo, and submit the form.

This POST request will do something and return, among other things, the foo value back to the same page. Basically, I just want the value to be there as the user set it when the page is re-rendered after the POST request. Pretty much standard stuff I think.

The HTML file I have something like:

```
 <div>
     <label for="foo">Foo:</label>
        {% if foo is defined %}
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="foo" value={{ foo }} name = "foo">
        {% else %}
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="foo" name = "foo">
        {% endif %}
 </div>
```

My question is twofold:

1) What's a better way to do the above? I imagine there might just be some one-liner or anyway a "more elegant" way of doing that. However, I'm new to Flask and Jinja2 and I couldn't figure it out yet.

2) Pycharm signals an error for the duplicate reference id. If that is not fixed by question 1), how can I get rid of that?

**EDIT**: I think I was thrown off-balance by PyCharm message when I first tried to put the if statement inside the html tags:

[image]

Comment: You can do separate GET endpoint with JSON after user POST action and replace elements with JS without need for full reload. If-else can be still needed if eg. user clears cache without session cookie.

Comment: About duplicate ID - it's if-else so it's not duplicate, you can ignore it.

Comment: @Zydnar thanks for the comments. Yeah I know I can ignore it. The red marks are just annoying tho and I'd like to know how to get rid of those. Possibly by avoiding repeating myself writing two times the <input> line.

Comment: I think, this can be treated as bug, you can report  it at: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It quite simple actually, you just place the if statement inside the `<input>`, e.g. `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="foo" {% if foo is defined %} value="{{ foo }}" {% endif %} name = "foo">`

Note as well, that you should probably put your `{{foo}}`  inside quotes in case they contain spaces, etc (e.g. `value=bla bla` is invalid html, `value="bla bla"` is valid html).

An even cleaner solution would be this:

`<input type="text" class="form-control" id="foo"  value="{{ foo or "" }}"  name = "foo">`

If `foo` is passed to `render template`, its value is rendered. Else, an empty string is rendered.

Comment: Thanks! That looks pretty simple indeed. I didn’t know you can put the Jinja code inside the tags... although I should have imagined that since I have some experience with other templates after all. Will try that on Monday and get back to you. Thanks again.

Comment: Looks like it's working. I edited my question to insert a screenshot. Indeed I had thought about putting the statement into the tags, but that message made me desist without even trying. My bad I suppose.